# C++ override error for signatures of const int and int&

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am compiling a C++ program by GCC 7.5.0, but it complained about ambiguous override functions `bool ReadRegister(const uint16_t, const uint16_t)` and `bool ReadRegister(const uint16_t, uint16_t &)`. The `const uint16_t` and `uint16_t &` are completely different data types, am I wrong about it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How exactly are you using `ReadRegister()` that is causing ambiguity?

Comment: If you provide a non-`const` `uint16_t` as the `length` argument, how does it know which version to call? Either one would be valid (I don't know the overload resolution rules well enough to say if one is supposed to be preferred by the standard's rules, but I'll say that it's not at all obvious to me, and when the behavior could be *very* different I wouldn't like to risk users accidentally getting their values modified for failure to mark `const`).

Comment: It is not the function issue but the compiling error for overriding  uint16_t & and const uint16_t, the GCC indicated that the data type (uint16_t &) and (uint16_t) are ambiguous, it apparently totally different data types, sadly nothing can I do about it, but accepted not to use an override.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.When you call the readRegister function, the compiler doesn't know which one you're calling,it will report 'call of overload is ambiguous' error.

In C++,Reference Binding does not have a const qualified conversion.Direct reference bindings compare to pass-values only at the Exact Match  and Derived to Base Conversion.more details in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

For example:

```
void f(int (*)() noexcept); // #1
void f(int (*)()); // #2

void g(int (&)() noexcept); // #3
void g(int (&)()); // #4
```

#1 has a higher priority than #2, while #3 and #4 are equal.So just memorize the rules.

Comment: void g(int (&)() noexcept); // #3
void g(int )()); // #4, is that #3 and #4 equal?

Comment: yes,in your condition.one of the arguments is of the same type as the parameter. The other function is of the same type as adding a top-level const to the argument.
All belong to the exact match, cannot distinguish the priority, can only report an error